# Android Marshmallow USB OTG issue

Tags: android, usb, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a problem with the *OTG* function on *Marshmallow*.

With *Lollipop* when I plugged my external storage , I could access the files on my *OTG* storage with the Storage Access Framework.
Now when I plug it with *Marshmallow* I can't access my files with my apps as if my *OTG* storage was not mounted as before.
 
I used *ES Explorer* with *Lollipop* and my *OTG Storage* was mounted in `/storage/USBstorage1` but now it is recognize as `usb://` and I think it is why I can't access my file with my apps now.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest Marshmallow update you have to now request "dangerous permissions" at run-time.

http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous